# Jquery Increment Down Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, counting

I cant seem to work out why this wont work, if you check the link bellow then add 3 guest then remove one the counter goes mental.

http://www.waterfrontexeter.co.uk/preordernew/

```
    var count = 1;
    $(".removeOrder").on('click', function(){

                count--;
                $("#counter").html("Total Number of Guest: " + count);
                $("input[id=totalguest]").val("Total Number of Guest: " + count);

        });
```

This is my code so far, everything looks fine I think? I tried the reverse of this and it added up fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, the problem is that the js-code on your website is not well structured. To escape this kind of errors, I recommend you to do it in more flexible way:

```
...
count = $(".duplicate").length; 
...
```

Or, even better, you can write strings directly and don't store counter in a variable:

```
var strCount = '';
...
strCount = "Total Number of Guest: " + $(".duplicate").length;
$("#counter").html(strCount);
$("input[id=totalguest]").val(strCount);
```

Comment: Sorry the duplicate bit is nothing to do with count, all i need to do is take away once someone has pressed .removeOrder

Answer (score 1):

One problem you're going to have is that you're creating new click handlers every time that you click the add guest button...

```
$(".add").click(function () {
    $(".removeOrder").on('click', function(){
        $(this).parents(".duplicate").remove();
        count--;
        $("#counter").html("Total Number of Guest: " + count);
        $("input[id=totalguest]").val("Total Number of Guest: " + count);
    });
});
```

What's happening when you run this, you're adding lots of extra click handlers.

As a rule of thumb, never add click handlers inside of an event callback.

To fix it, you should move the click handler to a delegated event...

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeOrder', function(){
    $(event.target).closest(".duplicate").remove();
    count--;
    $("#counter").html("Total Number of Guest: " + count);
    $("input[id=totalguest]").val("Total Number of Guest: " + count);
});
```

Comment: Haha, no worries. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Either way, still try and remember not to ever put a click handler in a callback function.